# Vertical line nested/interlaced groups within table

Tags: html, css

I have the following requirements to draw lines between groups within the table (where groups can be nested and interlaced). I'm wondering if anyone has any simple/smart ways of being able to do this?

[image]

My current best idea is that each row maintains the state of what groups its a part of and how indented that group is. Then when rendering I render divs/spans which are "floated" left, provide the necessary indenting and if required line style. Even though I think this would "work", I'm left wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: do you have any HTML and CSS to bring along ??

Comment: At the moment all I have is the table with the content... no grouping logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make that vertical line I would use a div's, in the table cells, with inline-block and borders.

```
<td>
    <div style="display: inline-block; border-left: 1px solid #000;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;">
        Test Group1
    </div>
</td>
<!-- ...ect -->
```

And then on the last row in the Group you also have a bottom border on that div.

```
<td>
    <div style="display: inline-block; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 30px;">
        Test Group3
    </div>
</td>
```

Obviously if you need it to just happen automatically you will need to work a bit of programing magic in PHP and/or Javascript to figure out when the borders are needed.

Do note you will need the non-breaking space (&nbsp) otherwise the div will collapse to a 0 pixel element and no borders will be visible. You may also have to set the div height so that the borders look like one continuous line. And the Table cells (td's) and table rows (tr's) should have no padding or margins. If padding or margins is needed for the text set it in the text divs.

Comment: This is the same as the approach I was thinking. Was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: There is nothing that would be native to HTML CSS or Javascript. I would almost guarantee there's a third party library that can create some kind of expandable tree structure for you. But with any library you have to deal with the bloat, figuring out how someone else's code works, and then there is issue of it no longer being maintained. For me I find it far easier to build what I need. Also off the top of my head I would guess that with about 40 to 50 lines of PHP/Javascript you can have it done automatically for you.

Comment: JS will be generating the required HTML, so I'm not worried about that part. I'm just looking for a better approach in general.